# Call methods inside public folder - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, tinymce

I am using Responsive Filemanager and Tinymce in my laravel multisite project. Those files are in my public folder and the filemanager uses config.php file to setup upload directory. For every site I want to use different upload folder. What i want to do is dynamically change the upload directory using by using some method e.g.

```
Config::get('upload.foldername');
```

or

```
Session::get('site.foldername');
```

How do i do that?

app/config/upload.php looks like this

```
<?php
return array(
    'foldername' => 'site1'
);
```

if the url is site2.example.com, I change the config file from my filter

```
$host = Request::getHost();
$parts = explode('.', $host);
$subdomain = $parts[0];
Config::set('upload.foldername', $subdomain);
```

Comment: Please can you show your config. Also improve your question for better understanding

Comment: Its just an example. I just wanted to ask if it is possible to call any methods on a php file inside public folder?

Comment: You can access config from laravel views not sure about public. Public folder should contain only assets

Comment: yeah i know but how to use it inside public/filemanager/config/config.php

Comment: OK I can see what you want to do. Why not move file manager to app\filemanager and handle the logic in controller? As far as I know it won't work in public since laravel discourage that

Comment: you have typo mistake here Config::set('uppload.foldername', $subdomain);? "uppload" -> "upload" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you save that file with .blade.php extension, included it in your view and then call Config like this

```
Config::set('uppload.foldername', $subdomain); // where subdomain your get it with Request::url() or your own method
```

EDIT

Rename config.php to config.blade.php

In config.blade.php do `<?php echo Config::get('upload.foldername') ?>` and wherever you want to include the config.blade.php do `<?php include('path/to/config.blade.php') ?>` I just tried it and it works alright

Comment: everything is working properly. I just want to call Config::get('upload.foldername') inside public/filemanager/config/config.php, is it possible?

Comment: actually you don't need to rename the file just do <?php echo Config::get('upload.foldername') ?> and include it with <?php include('path/to/config.php') ?>

Comment: @sushant am still confused why you must do this in public folder. Please where can I find your file manager? Is it a package that exists on its own? My concern is that this not a good approach. Why must file manager be in public folder

Comment: @Digitlimit I agree with you I just showed him a way of doing it, is definitely not the way to go